# How to create two pipelines in bitbucket?

Tags: git, heroku, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I have two applications in Heroku. One is staging and another is production. Currently in my BitBucket, the master branch will be deployed to the production server in Heroku. I would like my staging branch to be deployed to the staging server in Heroku.

This is my bitbucket-pipelines.yml for production

```
image: node:6
clone:
  depth: full
pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
        - step:
            script:
              - npm install
              - npm test
              - git config --global user.email "abc@abc.com"
              - git config --global user.name "abc@abc.com"
              - git push https://heroku:$HEROKU_API_KEY@git.heroku.com/$HEROKU_APP_NAME_PRODUCTION.git HEAD
```

How can I create another bitbucket-pipelines.yml for staging branch which push to staging server ?

Answer (score 0):

You should have the same bitbucket-pipelines.yml files across all your branches. The rules in the configuration will determine what pipeline executes.

You can have a configuration like this that will deploy to master when the master branch changes, and likewise will deploy to staging when the staging branch changes.

```
image: node:6
clone:
  depth: full
pipelines:
  branches:
    master: # Only runs when master branch is changed. Deploys to production.
        - step:
            script:
              - npm install
              - npm test
              - git config --global user.email "abc@abc.com"
              - git config --global user.name "abc@abc.com"
              - git push https://heroku:$HEROKU_API_KEY@git.heroku.com/$HEROKU_APP_NAME_PRODUCTION.git HEAD
    staging: # Only runs when staging branch is changed. Deploys to staging.
        - step:
            script:
              - npm install
              - npm test
              - git config --global user.email "abc@abc.com"
              - git config --global user.name "abc@abc.com"
              - git push https://heroku:$HEROKU_API_KEY@git.heroku.com/$HEROKU_APP_NAME_STAGING.git HEAD
```